# Why does Fastlane throw exception "Code Sign error: No code signing identities found"?

Tags: ios, react-native, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

My Keychain Access contains my iPhone app's public and private key, which I just recently created and downloaded. However, when trying to use Fastlane Deliver, I get the following error:

Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found.

I've looked around and tried various things to no avail.

What are you supposed to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is checklist

- Your provisioning profile contain **Distribution certificate**
- **Distribution certificate** public and private key are valid in your keychain

If it is, just try to manually upload with XCode to see whether it is successful or not.